# See if date selected is future from today - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, date, compare

I have to compare the date that they want to put in and the current date today, and if they have put in a date that is in the future, then alert them to change the date, otherwise insert the data.

Basically I am having issues comparing the dates. here is my code:

```
var today = year + '-' + month + '-' + day + ' 00:00:00';

var d1 = new Date(postdate); // postdate = 2014/02/01 ie: 1 Feb 2014
var d2 = new Date(today); // todays date
if(d1>d2){
    alert('You cannot post in the future!');
}
```

But that doesnt seem to work. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Make sure that JS is properly parsing your string. If you're passing a string in to Date(), it has to be a recognizable format: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Answer (score 0):

Convert the dates into a comparable number, like milliseconds.

```
if(d1.valueOf()>d2.valueOf()){
    alert('You cannot post in the future!');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create a new variable `today`.
If by today you are trying to get today's date, you can simply do
`var today = new Date();`

```
var d1 = new Date(postdate); // postdate = 2014/02/01 ie: 1 Feb 2014
//----------
var d2 = new Date(year,month,day); // todays date
//----------

if(d1>d2){
    alert('You cannot post in the future!');
}
```

Remember `month` is 0 based index. So, for december it would be 11.

Answer (score 0):

Compare the dates with the same format, if today is 2014-01-24 00:00:00 then postdate also should be 2014-02-01 00:00:00

Then use + prefix to compare milliseconds:

```
if(+d1 > +d2){
    alert('You cannot post in the future!');
}
```